# Opening a specific tab when a attribute on the map is clicked on?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

When i click on a attribute in my leaflet map I want to display the information in a specific tab. If the right tab isn't open already, i want the right tab to open and display the information when a attribute on the map gets clicked on.

For example:
[image]

This is my html code:

```
<!-- tab 4 -->
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
    <h4>Information</h4>
    <p>In this tab you will find specific information about the selected attribute. </p>       
</div>
```

And this is my js code:

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.on({
                    click: function showResultsInDiv() {
                        var d= document.getElementById('tab4');
                        d.innerHTML =  "ID:" + feature.properties.id + "<br> X-as:" + feature.properties.x + "<br> Y-as:" + feature.properties.y + "<br> Keten:" + feature.properties.keten + "<br> Naam:" + feature.properties.name;
                    }
                }); }
        //Hier wordt de data daadwerkelijk toegevoegd aan de map
    }).addTo(map);
```

UPDATE SOLUTION:

Underneath this line: `d.innerHTML =.......` I added this line of code and it works:

```
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#tab4"]').tab('show');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the 'window.location' to point to the tab's id:

```
window.location = "#tab4";
```

In case you're using a framework like Bootstrap to manage the tabs, you can use it's JS API:

```
$("#tab4").tab('show')
```

Comment: I tried your solution. But it doesn't open the tab.

Comment: does the change reflect in the location bar in the browser? could you host the example somewhere to help with debugging?

Comment: what're you using to handle the tabs? if it's bootstrap, does this show your tab: `$("#tab4").tab('show')`?

Comment: Yeah in the location bar it changes to /#tab4 but on screen it doesn't move to tab 4. I am using bootstrap to show my tabs. Do i need to implement $("#tab4").tab('show') under this line:  d.innerHTML = ?

Comment: I got it working. See my update. Thanks for the help r0hitsharma!

Comment: great. can you add your answer or select mine (added and edit) to close it as done?